# Download file from NodeJS Server using Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, download

I want to download a file from the server using node js. However, the download is not executed and the pdf content is entered as data as in the first image.
I want to download like the second picture.

```
 var file_path = path.join(__dirname, '../PDF', category, itemName);

 console.log(file_path);//ex)C:\Users\zhfld\Desktop\cloudproject-master (4)\cloudproject-master\PDF\cosmetic\perfume
 res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=' + itemName + '.pdf');
 res.download(file_path + ".pdf");//ex)C:\Users\zhfld\Desktop\cloudproject-master (4)\cloudproject-master\PDF\cosmetic\perfume.pdf
```

[image: web message(F12)]

[image: I want]

Comment: You do an `XMLHttpRequest`, why do you expect that this would trigger a download?

Comment: @t.niese 
This is my first project. I have a hard time understanding your words. But I'll try to understand a little bit.  I used res.download so I think it should trigger the download.        And I have a question. Should I change the XMLHttpRequest?

Comment: Referring to your comments, while Googling, I saw an article about setting the responseType to blob and followed it, and it was solved. thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `express` you can do that:

```js
app.get('/download', function(req,res){
    const file = `${__dirname}/folder/file.pdf`;
    res.download(file);
}
```